# Change the default alert messages from Django Allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using the standard login templates from django-allauth and I wish to style the alert box differently than the default one provided. (And also remove the `<ul>` tags through a custom class)

e.g

```
class DivErrorList(ErrorList):
        def __str__(self):
            return self.as_divs()
        def as_divs(self):
            if not self: return ''
            return '%s' % ''.join([e for e in self])
```

1) How would I style the alert?

2) How do I add a custom class to the loginform?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Trying to do this now. The best I came up with so far is to essentially overwrite the SignUpForm provided by django-allauth and add something like this to the __init__ method: ```self.error_class = DivErrorList```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, first, you need to overwrite the form. So in your app add `forms.py` and something like this to it:

```py
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

# If you are impotying the DivErrorList from somewhere else
from {custom_location} import DivErrorList

class CustomSignUpForm(Login):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(CustomSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.error_class = DivErrorList
```

Then tell django-allauth to use this form. In `settings.py` add:

```py
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
  'signup': '{app_location}.forms.CustomSignUpForm'
}
```

That should do the trick.